# Rails Routing Constraints and UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, routes

I need to handle routes like `/:slug`. The slugs are constrained elsewhere to match:

```
\A[\p{Alnum}_.-]{3,}\z
```

The obvious routes:

```
get '/:slug' => '...', :constraints => { :slug => /[\p{Alnum}_.-]{3,}/ }
get '/:slug' => '...', :slug => /[\p{Alnum}_.-]{3,}/
```

work fine with ASCII URLs like `/mu-is-too-short` and `/where.is.pancakes.house` but everything falls apart when the URL is `/µ-is-too-short`. The browser is sending this to the server:

```
/%C2%B5-is-too-short
```

and Rails is trying to check the encoded `%C2%B5-is-too-short` against the `:slug` constraint and failing because `%` is not a `\p{Alnum}`.

I have come up with two kludges:

```
get '/:slug' => '...', :slug => /.{3,}/
get '/:slug' => '...', :slug => /[^\/]+/, :constraints => lambda { |r| r.path_parameters[:slug].to_s =~ /\A[\p{Alnum}_.-]{3,}\z/ }
```

The `:slug => /[^\/]+/` in the second is needed to keep Rails from thinking that the `.b` in `a.b` is a format extension.

Is there a way to make Rails behave sensibly and check the decoded `:slug` against the constraints or do I have to loosen the constraints or do it by hand?

Comment: So the problem basically is that params matched with constraints are not url decoded, am I right?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: Yes. Rails does have the decoded value in `r.path_parameters[:slug]` but it doesn't seem to be using it for the constraint check. I just had to add `:slug => /[^\/]+/` to the second one to get Rails to properly extract a slug with a `.` in it, that implies a few things about the parsing order.

Comment: This was pretty obvious looking at your question but I just wanted to clear it out. I tried looking into Rails code of routing and gave up.

Comment: I was thinking about making a regexp that would match all allowed letters/signs but in utf-8 space that would be too complicated. Blacklisting does't look very promising as well.

Comment: The problem is that Rails doesn't seem to use the UTF-8 form so a regex would have to UTF-8-ify the slug before applying the Unicode character class test. I've been trying to avoid going into the Rails source, past experience with the Rails internals suggest that it would be an incredibly frustrating and hair pulling experience and I just shaved my head so that would be pretty messy. I'll probably end up throwing on my hazmat suit and wading through the source anyway.

Comment: Can you give me some idea about what mess I did [there](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5033057#new) ?

Comment: You may be interested in Rails 5, which accepts utf-8 characters in a path name, file name, etc. If not, then try to find the HEX conversion of the mew character, and ruby will handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda for the constraint and this way change the encoding (from http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/2/21/use-lambdas-for-rails3-route-constraints):

```
scope :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank? } do
  # all my logged in routes
end
```

Comment: This is just my second kludge (`:constraints => lambda { |r| ... }`) in disguise though. I'm looking for a way to convince Rails to behave sensibly and check the constraints against the decoded path that it already has.